# How to save the cookies of a WebView? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to include a website in my app where you have to login. I would like to save the cookies once you logged in, so you have to login only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out it does that automatically.

Comment: after wasting lot of times. this answer saved me